# Can phylocode classify viruses?

Tags: classification

Can phylocode classify viruses? Based on what I found this system began in 2019, so there is not much information about it.

I know that the Linnaean classification system cannot classify viruses, but what about this new classification system (phylocode)?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In general, we expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). In particular, please add links and references about "phylocode" and why you think it might be useful compared to existing viral classifications. Thanks! 

Answer (score 2):

[PhyloCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhyloCode) is not a new system but it isn't popular yet and actually quite opposed by some.

It overlaps with the ranked based systems but does not nullify them, meaning that even if PhyloCode becomas popular the ranked systems will still be needed.

One might understand from your question that virus have no classification system, but [they have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus_classification). The common one is called ICTV.

PhyloCode can classify virus and there is already a classification for virus (ICTV)